# Retrieve data from selected text input among various text inputs with same name & id upon hitting Enter

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

I have several text input dynamically created with same id and same name. I want to fetch the data being typed in a particular text input whenever a user presses 'Enter' key in that text input.

For eg., I have

```
<input type="text" id="fetchChatMsg" name="chat" />
<input type="text" id="fetchChatMsg" name="chat" />
<input type="text" id="fetchChatMsg" name="chat" />
<input type="text" id="fetchChatMsg" name="chat" />
```

Each input has been created dynamically on some event. Now let say, there are 4 text inputs on the screen. User can type anything in them. I want that whenever a user presses the 'Enter' key in any text input, the data in that particulat text-input should be alerted.

I have used:

```
$(document).on('keypress','#fetchChatMsg', function(e) {
    if(e.which==13)
        alert($('#fetchChatMsg').val());
});
```

But it's really ambiguous. Please sort this out, maybe classes can handle this ?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate ID's, its invalid html. Use class instead.

Comment: use class instead of ids

Comment: Give them all the same class instead of the same id, then do $('.className') to select them all.

Comment: will using class solve this issue ? How will it knoe the data has come from ?

Comment: Yes, and use `this.value` instead of `$('#fetchChatMsg').val()`

Comment: doesn't the event args have a .source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, without duplicate ID's but class instead.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('keypress','.fetchChatMsg', function(e) {
    if(e.which==13)
        alert(this.value);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="fetchChatMsg" name="chat" />
<input type="text" class="fetchChatMsg" name="chat" />
<input type="text" class="fetchChatMsg" name="chat" />
<input type="text" class="fetchChatMsg" name="chat" />
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JwB5z/)